# Is it possible to backup a disk on a Windows shared folder?

Tags: backup, disk-utility

I connected to Windows 10 shared folder:

[image]

checked that it is writable by creating a file and tried [to backup a disk](https://developernote.com/2021/11/how-to-backup-entire-disk-on-macos/) into the that shared folder, but with no success:

[image]

what can be wrong with the permissions?

Folder info:

[image]

**EDIT1:**
Created and mounted HFS+ disk, but TimeMachine does not allow to select it:

[image]

```
defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1
```

does not help.

Comment: What version of macOS, please.

Comment: @IconDaemon System Version: macOS 11.6 (20G165),  Kernel Version: Darwin 20.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have done this with a TimeMachine, to a *shared* NTFS formatted drive. It's been a few years but this should still work. EG pardon the 100 foot view, I don't remember all the details.

Share the drive (or a folder on the drive, which I did) on Windows and give a username you can share with the Mac backup app. Give that user CHANGE permission on the share.

Then you create a sparse image **on the Mac**, mount the image once created and format it appropriately (at the time it was HFS+ *only*) on the Mac and then copy the DMG you just created and formatted to the share on the Windows PC/Server.

macOS can't write to a *directly attached* NTFS drive natively without 3rd party software, but it can write to an SMB share, regardless of the filesystem.

The DMG is required so you don't lose the APFS/HFS+ extended attributes that NTFS does'nt really support. And if you are using TimeMachine it **HAS** to back up to HFS+, or for more recent macOS versions APFS.

So in reality you are not backing up directly to NTFS but a Mac filesystem *on* an NTFS share.

Comment: I found a post on Time Machine, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281/can-i-use-time-machine-to-back-up-data-to-a-windows-shared-drive . Should I run `defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1` in the terminal?

Comment: Created and mounted HFS+ disk, but TimeMachine does not allow to select it

Comment: Yah, sorry, I don't remember the details but there was a command you had to run to allow TimeMachine to either select the mounted volume or to actually select it in the terminal command. It *may* have been a TMUTIL command, but  I do't specifically recall, sorry.